# Angular FontAwesome not being loaded

Tags: angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm working on a project where we have an Angular application. Beside this we have a small library with components to be used across multiple applications. Within this library I use FontAwesome. I will give some explanation later, but the problem I currently have is that FontAwesome works when I run "ng serve", but after building it on CI and using that artifact I get the error message: "FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=linkedin and prefix=fab".

Context library:
I have an Generic Module that includes all components. This module includes a custom Module looking something like this:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faLinkedin } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faLinkedin';
...
library.add(faLinkedin, ...);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  exports: [
    FontAwesomeModule
  ]
})
export class .... {}
```

There is a component in the "ComponentLibraryModule" (which has imported the FA-module) that uses these icons. The component using this icons is used in the library itself and not in the Angular application like this:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'linkedin']"></fa-icon>
```

This library is a dependency of the Angular application. Next to this I import the "ComponentLibraryModule" too.

When I run a "ng-serve" command the icons show up perfectly, but when I use the artifact from the CI server it all goes wrong and I get an error ("FontAwesome: Could not find icon with iconName=linkedin and prefix=fab").

By importing the custom FA-module and using it in the component I though it should work everywhere, but it seems like that is not the case.

I don't know what could be the problem here. I use ng-packagr to build the library, but I don't know if that might cause this issue. Anybody has experience with this and/or might have an idea?

Package.json:

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.4",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
```

Comment: which version of angular you are using? just remove it from your exports  this link may help https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome or https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular

Comment: I used both Angular 6 and 7

Comment: In addition: I can't remove the export of FontAwesomeModule. It breaks the code (fa-icon is not a known element:)